# how to refresh Yii captcha when validation failed?

Tags: yii

how to refresh the Yii captcha word image when validation failed ?
here's my code

```
            jQuery.ajax({
                    type    : "POST",
                    cache   : false,
                    url     : emailfrienddata,
                    data    : 'friendemail='+friendemail+'&sendername='+sendername+'&friendemailcontent='+friendemailcontent+"&captcha="+captcha,
                        success :function(data){
                            if(data == 1){
                             alert('Email Sent');   
                            jQuery.fancybox.close();
                            } else if(data == 2) {
                                alert('wrong captcha!');
//HOW TO REFRESH YII CAPTCHA IN THIS AREA ?
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                });
            return false;   
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger a click on the refresh button. If you put the captcha in a container with class `captcha` you could:

```
$(".captcha a").trigger("click");
```

Comment: kindly explain more.. i didn't simply get what you meant :))

Comment: I think you have a captcha on your page, right? Near the captcha there's usually a button to refresh the captcha. With the snippet above you can simulate a click on that button and the captcha is refreshed. You just need to make sure, that you put your captcha e.g. in a `<div class="captcha">`.